# lost windows while dual booting with ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I installed ubuntu with windows 10, from the steps of installation i followed a video and chose " something else " that's dedicated to choose partitions and so.
In the location of installing the OS on i picked "windows 10 loader" , the tutorial said choose windows 10 boot manager, but that option was not mentioned so i thought it might be the same, what i ended up with now is i cannot boot back to my windows from the boot if i choose either Ubuntu or windows 10 loader i get to ubuntu not windows, gladly i still have the partition including almost every single file of my windows OS. is there anything to do to boot to windows once again?

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry. Use some windows installation medium or rescue medium, like rescue-CD, rescue-USB-stick or Universal Boot CD to boot into Windows (save mode) and reinstall the windows 10 loader. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows) how to proceed.